# What does $|w| \leq w_c$ means?

Tags: absolute-value

$|w| \leq w_c$ means?

Does it mean $-w_c\leq w \leq w_c$ or

$0\leq w \leq w_c$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is $w$ real or complex? Also, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the tag modular-arithmetic (please read the tag description).

Comment: @Community I am not understanding what mod w<=$w_c$ means.

Comment: @HansLundmark w is real here.

Comment: And your strange notation on the left-hand side means $|w|$?

Comment: Ah yes @HansLundmark

Comment: So if, say, $w=-2$ and $w_c=3$, would you say that $|-2|<3$ is true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Without context, I think that the correct option is $\omega_c\leq\omega\leq\omega_c$. But, you should better explain the problem.

Comment: Well, that *surely* isn't the correct option! But if you correct the typo, it might be. :-)